# How can convert a char date into a date format

Tags: r, date, char

```
a <- c("2-Apr-2021", "31-Mar-2018")
head(a)
# [1] "2-Apr-2021"  "31-Mar-2018"
b <- strptime(a, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
head(b)
# [1] NA NA
```

I tried to convert char to date by strptime. but return NA NA. Could you please advise?

Comment: `b <- as.Date(a, '%d-%b-%y')` should work. Note that `%b` is locale-specific meaning your locale should be English for it to understand 'Apr', 'Mar' etc.

Comment: `dmy` from `lubridate` should work

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` you can do the following:

(Note that I need to change the month abbreviations since my system language is different)

```
# convert the string to date format
tmp1 <- as.Date(c("2-Apr-2021", "31-Mär-2018"), format = "%d-%b-%Y")

# change the output format
format(tmp1, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
# "02-04-2021" "31-03-2018"

## Using strptime() ##

# convert to date
tmp1 <- strptime(c("2-Apr-2021", "31-Mär-2018"), format = "%d-%b-%Y")

# format
format(tmp1, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
#  "02-04-2021" "31-03-2018"
```

or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

format(dmy(c("2-Apr-2021", "31-Mär-2018")), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
# "02-04-2021" "31-03-2018"
```

---

**Update**

```
tmp1 <- as.Date(df[, 1], format = "%d-%b-%y")

format(tmp1, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

# [1] "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021"
# [11] "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "02-04-2021" "31-03-2021" "31-03-2021" "31-03-2021" "31-03-2021"
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date_adj = c("2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "31-Mär-21", "31-Mär-21", "31-Mär-21", "31-Mär-21" )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: When i used the first suggestion recommended above.
The result is something like below 
["0021-04-02" "0021-04-02"] after the as.Date command
["02-04-0021" "02-04-0021"] after the format command

seems something wrong in the year. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @pirce_ata please share a snippet of your data, so I can recreate the error. You can easily do that by pasting the output of  `dput(head(test, 20))` into your question.

Comment: structure(list(date_adj = c("2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", 
"2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", 
"2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", "2-Apr-21", 
"2-Apr-21", "31-Mar-21", "31-Mar-21", "31-Mar-21", "31-Mar-21"
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")